# SQL Query : populating only null value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run the following query using SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

```
update Schema.[ClientNew]  
set [Notes] = ([Notes]+ char(10)+(Select [Notes] from Schema.[clientOld]
where  office = 90  and ID = '123456789AM')) where  office = 90  and ID= '123456789'
```

Basically trying to combine all data in my notes field from clientOld to notes field in clientnew.

This is just part of the code.

When broken apart:

```
 Select [Notes] from Schema.[clientOld] where  office = 90  and ID = '123456789AM'
```

gives me data in the notes field.

But when I run the query only {null} value appears on the clientNew table.

is my query wrong?? or writing null values somewhere?

Please advise,

Comment: ClientNew has in Notes null values before the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  `Schema.[ClientNew]` got `Null` in the field `[Notes]`, you update will not work.

This is because you can't operate with `Null` using the operator `+`

example:

do this:

```
select null + 'a'
```

and the result will be `null`.
So, if your table ClientNew got NULL values, this

```
([Notes]+ char(10)+(Select [Notes] from Schema.[clientOld]
where  office = 90  and ID = '123456789AM'))
```

will return Null

Try to add an empty string instead

```
(ISNULL([Notes], '') + char(10)+(Select [Notes] from Schema.[clientOld]
where  office = 90  and ID = '123456789AM'))
```

Comment: yes. null value was the issue. I knew it was something silly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

A NULL + anything always equals NULL, You need to use COALESCE to prevent the NULLs:

```
UPDATE    [Schema].ClientNew
SET              Server = COALESCE([Schema].ClientNew, '') + COALESCE([Schema].clientOld, '')
FROM         [Schema].ClientNew INNER JOIN
                      [Schema].clientOld ON [Schema].clientOld.office = [Schema].ClientNew.office AND ID = [Schema].ClientNew.ID
WHERE     (office = 90) AND (ID = '123456789AM')
```